# How to give a moment in ajax between commands

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want add a few second before redirect to url

```
$(document).on("click", ".post-dataDraft", function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Lap_geologi/postAll'); ?>",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $('#konfirmasiPost').modal('hide');
        $('.msg').html(data);
        effect_msg();
        //I need a moment here
        window.location='<?php echo base_url('Lap_geologi'); ?>';
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
})
```

How to add a few moment in tag //

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {window.location=...}, <whatever moment you need in ms>);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "setTimeout" as follows :

```
$(document).on("click", ".post-dataDraft", function() {
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Lap_geologi/postAll'); ?>",
})
.done(function(data) {
    $('#konfirmasiPost').modal('hide');
    $('.msg').html(data);
    effect_msg();
    //I need a moment here
    setTimeout(function() {
      //redirect here
      window.location='<?php echo base_url('Lap_geologi'); ?>';
    }, 5000);

})
.error(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

})

Comment: Thx bruh for example

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` for this.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  // your code here
  window.location='<?php echo base_url('Lap_geologi'); ?>';
}, 1000);
```

The `1000` is the timeout in milliseconds, so in this case the callback will be called after 1 second.